# Use jQuery Deferred.done().fail() or Deferred.then()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I know that Deferred.done(a).fail(b) is identical to Deferred.then(a,b), apart from their syntax, but I want to know if there's a preferred way of syntax.

Why would I use one over the other? Is there a best practice?
The only argument that I can come up with right now is that if I encounter the fail function 'b' in the .done(a).fail(b) situation, I *know immediately* that it is a fail function when I see fail(b), while I do *not* see that when I just see b in the then(a,b) situation. Any more arguments?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.done(a).fail(b)` is a more semantic approach, so I go for that.

Comment: `.then(doneFn, failFn)` is *not* the same as  `.done(doneFn).fail(failFn)`

Comment: an explanation would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use Deferred.then(a,b) when you have multiple tasks to get done or fail on.

e.g.

```
$.when(task1)
.then(task2, task1Failure)
.then(task3, task2Failure)
.fail(task3Failure);
```

or

```
$.when(task1)
.then(task2, task1Failure)
.then(task3, task2Failure)
.then(task3SuccessMeaningAllSuccess, task3Failure);
```

Comment: Please remember that when using `.then()` you should be returning values in the functions, or subsequent `.then()` calls will receive null as its data